# Problem managing User Profile Service

Tags: user-profile-service, configuration, user-configuration

I had a brand new Sharepoint Farm... I tried to installa User Profile Service and everying goes well.

When i tried to access to the Manage Area, I get an "unexpected exception".

If i look inside the log for more infos I find this:

```
Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sharepoint-ap:55555/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=dd1e8114%2D2ac2%2D4efa%2Da240%2Ddb3b9b3f5079))     
05/25/2012 15:24:52.52  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sharepoint-ap:55555/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=dd1e8114%2D2ac2%2D4efa%2Da240%2Ddb3b9b3f5079)  0cf48bf1-8802-4cea-9e45-a7d4dd99513a
05/25/2012 15:24:52.52  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sharepoint-ap:55555/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=dd1e8114%2D2ac2%2D4efa%2Da240%2Ddb3b9b3f5079)). Execution Time=1,07779061305278    0cf48bf1-8802-4cea-9e45-a7d4dd99513a
05/25/2012 15:24:52.52  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sharepoint-ap:55555/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=dd1e8114%2D2ac2%2D4efa%2Da240%2Ddb3b9b3f5079))     
05/25/2012 15:24:52.52  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sharepoint-ap:55555/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=dd1e8114%2D2ac2%2D4efa%2Da240%2Ddb3b9b3f5079)  61db75f3-8a8e-4b6e-969a-03b14b5495bf
05/25/2012 15:24:52.52  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  61db75f3-8a8e-4b6e-969a-03b14b5495bf
05/25/2012 15:24:52.58  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   et8j    High        UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.get_IsSynchronizationRunning()'.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart._LoadStatusAndSettings()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)  61db75f3-8a8e-4b6e-969a-03b14b5495bf
05/25/2012 15:24:52.59  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SynchronizationRunStatus.get_ConnectionName()'.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderSectionContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Html... 61db75f3-8a8e-4b6e-969a-03b14b5495bf
05/25/2012 15:24:52.59* w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...Form.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean in...  61db75f3-8a8e-4b6e-969a-03b14b5495bf
05/25/2012 15:24:52.59* w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...cludeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   61db75f3-8a8e-4b6e-969a-03b14b5495bf
05/25/2012 15:24:52.59  w3wp.exe (0x1010)                           0x0950  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sharepoint-ap:55555/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=dd1e8114%2D2ac2%2D4efa%2Da240%2Ddb3b9b3f5079)). Execution Time=88.2481572378612    61db75f3-8a8e-4b6e-969a-03b14b5495bf
05/25/2012 15:24:53.79  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0F40)                       0x10EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job SchedulingUnpublish)    2fcfd1c0-1773-416c-a9f0-f2f0bb42420f
```

Obv i tried with IISReset / Recycle App Pool and also a Machine Restart!

P.S.: DBs Are create on SQL Server..

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to delete the User Profile Service and recreate one?

Comment: do you have a recent CU installed ? SP1 ? did you ran PSConfig after updates ? what is the product installation status in the CA ?

Comment: @ Mike: yes, already tried
@SteveB: What's CU?

Comment: @ZibaLeah: CU = Cumulative Update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using? If you applied SP1 without the June CUs this is the behavior.

Comment: I'm using Enterprise version... What's CU?

Comment: How can I get cumulative updates? They are also called Hotfix? Thank you

Comment: A CU is a cumulative update. Between Service Packs, every 2 months Microsoft releases Updates. You have to apply them when you need parts of SharePoint repaired. You download them from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need start both "User Profile Service" and "User Profile Synchronization Service"  on the Central Administration.

Go to Central Admin > System Settings > Manage Services on Server

Check if both the services are started. You may have provisioned User Profile Service Application but from the log it appears that it appears that neccessary controls are failing to load due to which you get the exception.